# Dataweave Mule4 conditional statement error

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

how to use IF ELSE condition in Dataweave 2.0? I am trying to do a condition around one of the Payload Data Elements but its throwing error when I execute it.

```
Unable to resolve reference of method
Unable to resolve reference of attribute
```

Am I missing something?

XML >

```
    <payments>
    <payment>
        <custom-method>
            <method-name>AdyenComponent</method-name>
            <custom-attributes>
                <custom-attribute attribute-id="adyenPaymentMethod">iDEAL</custom-attribute>
            </custom-attributes>
        </custom-method>
        <amount>145.99</amount>
        <processor-id>Adyen_Component</processor-id>
        <transaction-id>851603387831889A</transaction-id>
        <custom-attributes>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="Adyen_log"></custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="authCode">Authorised</custom-attribute>
        </custom-attributes>
    </payment>
</payments>
```

Dataweave code

```
    %dw 2.0
    output application/json
    ns ns0 http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/order/2006-10-31
    ---
    [{
Ascent_FPL__Payment_Method__c   :   if ((payload.order.payments.payment.custom-method.custom-attributes.*custom-attribute filter(item) -> (item.@"attribute-id" == "adyenPaymentMethod")) [0] =="iDEAL") "iDEAL" else (payload.ns0#order.ns0#"custom-attributes".*ns0#"custom-attribute" filter(item) -> (item.@"attribute-id" == "creditCardType")) [0]
                        
    }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
ns ns0 http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/order/2006-10-31
---
    [{
Ascent_FPL__Payment_Method__c   :   if ((payload.order.payments.payment."custom-method"."custom-attributes".*"custom-attribute" filter(item) -> (item.@"attribute-id" == "adyenPaymentMethod")) [0] =="iDEAL") "iDEAL" else (payload.ns0#order.ns0#"custom-attributes".*ns0#"custom-attribute" filter(item) -> (item.@"attribute-id" == "creditCardType")) [0]
                        
    }]
```

As well you have an extra custom-attributes towards the end of the xml which you need to remove.

Comment: The change is mainly wrapping with quotes the attribute names that contain dashes so it doesn't get confused with the minus operation.

Comment: It worked thankyou! didn't know that wrapping with quotes is a problem, thankyou